# Kinetic JS Fire Paths events

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kineticjs

I have developed an interactive map using Kinetic JS based on the great tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404239/HTML5-Interactive-Map-using-SVG-Path-and-Polygon).

What I would like to achieve is to have below the map a list of staff located on the map, then have an event that if a visitor clicks the person's name from the list of names then the staff members location on the map is highlighted.

I have been working on this for a few hours trying to find the best solution, now I would settle for a working solution.

I have added an event listener to the li items, which fires correctly:

```
document.getElementById(stfArr[i]).addEventListener('click', function () { alert("true"); }, false);
```

But I cannot think of how I can call the path object.

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895614/selecting-kineticjs-path-by-id) mentioning stage.find(), however when I use this it doesn't seem to find any items from my map.

```
var room = stage.Find("#Room1")[0];
```

I have a JSON which is an object of objects and this is processed through a for loop, each location in the JSON file is processed:

```
var path = new Kinetic.Path({
  data: c,
  fill: '#fff',
  stroke: '#555',
  strokeWidth: 1
});
```

And each path has a few events:

```
path.on('mouseover', function () {
  this.setFill('#008000');
  this.setOpacity(1);
  mapLayer.drawScene();
});

path.on('mouseout', function () {
  this.setFill('#fff');
  // this.setAlpha(0.1);
  mapLayer.drawScene();
  tooltipBackground.hide();
  tooltip.hide();
  tooltipLayer.drawScene();
});
```

Then the path is added to the map layer:

```
mapLayer.add(path)
```

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt_65/fP598/) (this is my first time, so hopefully it works!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a capitalization typo:

```
stage.find  // not stage.Find
```

When you use the hashtag (#) within a .find key, KineticJS searches for a node `id`.

So when you create each path (room) you should assign it a node id (eg "Room1"):

```
var path = new Kinetic.Path({
  id:"Room1",
  data: c,
  fill: '#fff',
  stroke: '#555',
  strokeWidth: 1
});
```

Then your .find will succeed:

```
var room = stage.find("#Room1")[0];
```

Comment: Great, thanks for your help with this. I thought it would be something simple that I messed up.  Been able to fire mousedown and mouseover events so I am very much grateful for your help in getting past this challenge